Firebase: How can I get the authentication status of the current user?
I have this firebase.js file:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);


import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export let uid = null;

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    uid = user.uid;
  } else {
    uid = null;
  }
});

In another function I have been trying to do:
import {uid, auth} from "./firebase.js";
if (auth.currentUser)

or
if (uid)

However, neither works consistently. After sign the user will exist but after a page reload they disappear again. Is this the right way to check the user is signed in?

onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous and doesn't issue a callback immediately.  It can take some amount of time after the page is initially loaded before the callback verifies that the user is, in fact, signed in and validated.
When you say user "disappears", you are probably trying to observe the sign-in state immediately on page load, before the callback happens, which simply will never work the way you expect.  You need to wait for the result of the first callback in order to know when the user is signed in, and continue to listen to future callbacks to know if and when that changes.  You can add some logging to your app to better observe how this works in practice.
I suggest reading this article for more detailed information:
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0

I don't really understand how onauthstatechanged works. After reading some sources I had thought that it would set variable uid whenever the user logs in. Then when I refresh the page the uid will still be there. Is this wrong way to think about it?

When a browser page refreshes, all code and variables are reset and must be reloaded from whatever source they come from. That's always been the case in web development. There are no workarounds for this.

Oh right, this was my error. If I instead used usestate from react would that work?

I'm not familiar with that. Why don't you just give it a try?  If you have a problem, post a new question.
